# Instead of creating new chart in ChartJS, the new updated chart keeps the old data and adds the new

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I have been trying to solve this problem with ChartJS for a few days now, and I am completely stumped

My program shows the user a set of input elements they use to select data needing to be charted, plus a button that has an event to chart their data.  The first chart works great.  If they make a change to the data and click the button a second, third, or more time, all the data from the previous charts is plotted, PLUS their most recent selection.

It is behaving exactly like you might expect if the chart.destroy() object is not working, or perhaps would work if I created the chart object using a CONST (and could therefore add new data but not delete the beginning data).

I have tried all combinations of the browsers, chartjs and jquery libraries below:
Three different browsers:
• Chrome:  Version 107.0.5304.121 (Official Build) (64-bit)
• Microsoft Edge:  Version 107.0.1418.56 (Official build) (64-bit)
• Firefox:  107.0 64-bit
I have tried at least three different versions of Chart.js, including
• Versions 3.9.1
• 3.6.2
• 3.7.0
Jquery.js
• v3.6.1
• v1.11.1

Other things I have tried:

1. "use strict"   (no luck)
2. In addition to destroying the chart object, removed the div containing the canvas, and appending it again.
3. using setTimeout() function before updating the chart after destroying it  (because I thought maybe giving the destroy method more time might help)

[image: good chart]type here
[image: bad chart]

Software:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/chart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dropdownLists.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/chartDataFunctions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/chartJSFunctions.js"></script>

<body>
<div class = metadatasetup4" id = "buttons">
    <button class="download" id="getchart" value="Get Chart">Chart</button>
    <button class="download" id="downloadchart" value="Download">Download</button>
</div>

<div id = "bigchartdiv" class="bigchart">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
</body> 

<script>
$(window).on('load',function(){
//NOTE 1: In of my attempts to troubleshoot I tried strict mode (it didn't work)
//"use strict"; 
let data = {
    labels: lbl,
        datasets: [
        ]
};
let config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            type: 'linear',
            display: true,
            position: 'left',
            min:0,
            pointStyle:'circle',
          },
          y1: {
            type: 'linear',
            display: true,
            position: 'right',
            suggestedMax: 25,
            min: 0,
            pointStyle: 'cross',

            // grid line settings
            grid: {
              drawOnChartArea: false, // only want the grid lines for one axis to show up
            },
          },
        }                       
    }
};

// NOTE 2: The next line below, beginning with "var bigChartHTML =" was one of my later attempts to 
// solve the problem.  It didn't work, but my thought process was that if I removed 
// the div containing the canvas, AND destroyed the chart object, that appending a "fresh" 
// chart div to the body might be a work-around.  This did not work. 
var bigChartHTML = '<div id = "bigchartdiv" class="bigchart"><canvas id="myChart"></canvas></div>'


let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
let bigChart = null; 

// The getChartData() function below uses Ajax to populate various dropdown lists
// which enable the user to select the data is to be charted.  
// There are no chartjs-related operations in getChartData() 
getChartData();


$('#buttons').on('click','#getchart',function(){
    if (bigChart!=null) {
        
        //removeData(bigChart);
        bigChart.destroy();
        //bigChart = 1;

    }
    $("#bigchartdiv").empty();   //for this and next 2 lines, see NOTE 2 above
    $("#bigchartdiv").remove();  
    $(bigChartHTML).insertAfter("#chartcontrols");
    bigChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'),config);
    //NOTE 3: I thought maybe bigChart.destroy() took time, so I tried 
    //        using the setTimeout function to delay updating the chart
    //        (didn't work, but I left it in the code, anyway.)
    setTimeout(function() {updateChart(bigChart)}, 2000);
    //updateChart(bigChart);            
}); 


    // NOTE: The updateChart() function is actually included in "js/chartDataFunctions.js" 
    function updateChart(chart) {
            /*
            This section of the program reads the HTML elements then uses them
            to make an Ajax request to sql server, and these become the
            parameters for the newDataSet() function below.
            */
            
            newDataset(chart,firstElement,newdataset,backgroundcolor,color);        
    }
    
    // NOTE: The newDataSet() function is actually included in "js/chartJSFunctions.js" 
    // I show it here for brevity.   
    // It decides which axis (y or y1) to use to plot the datasets
    // the dataset is pushed into the data, and chart.update() puts it in the chart object
    function newDataset(chart,label,data,bgcolor='white',color='rgb(255,255,255)') {
        var maxValue = Math.max(...data);
        if (Number.isNaN(maxValue)) {
            return; 
        }
        if (maxValue == 0) {
            return;
        }
        var axisID = 'y';
        var ptStyle = 'circle';
        //var pStyle = 'circle';
        if (maxValue < 50) {
            axisID = 'y1';
            bgcolor = 'white';
            //ptStyle = 'Star'
        }
        chart.data.datasets.push({
            label:label,
            yAxisID:axisID,
            data:data,
            borderColor:color,
            backgroundColor:bgcolor,
            //pointStyle:ptStyle
        });
        chart.update();
    }

});


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around that solves my problem, but I still think this is a bug in  ChartJS.  Before calling bigChart.destroy(), I now do two things:  First, reset the data object back to it's original value, and second, reset the config object back to it's original value,  THEN call bigChart.destroy().

I think the destroy() method should handle that for me, but in my case, for whatever reason, it doesn't.

So, what I have is a work-around, not really a solution, but I'll take it.